# Can ionic bonds only have discrete distances?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-chemistry

If 2 atoms have an ionic bond, can they only be certain distances apart just like an electron can only be in discrete shells around the nucleus?

In other words, are ionic bonds quantum?

Answer (score 2):

All chemical bonds, and the whole universe in fact, are fundamentally quantum. While for a heavy object like a soccer ball the quantum nature is only of interest to the theorist, for chemical bonds the quantum nature is readily observable in spectroscopy and gives rise to signals such as discrete vibronic peaks in absorption spectra and discrete vibrational peaks in IR and Raman spectra. Now while the energy comes in discrete quanta, position is continuous. Just like a particle in a box or a quantum harmonic oscillator exists as a disperse wave function, a chemical bond exists as a quantum superposition of many bond lengths. Unlike the hydrogen atom which has eigenfunctions localized around particularly radii, a chemical bond is approximately described as a quantum harmonic oscillator, which has no radial nodes, and therefore no well defined radii (although the higher the energy in a quantum harmonic oscillator, the bigger the spatial variance in the wave function will be!) The shaking, spinning, etc mentioned in the other answer are most accurately described by the time-dependent many-body Schrodinger equation. For floppy molecules like proteins these dynamics can typically be well-approximated as classical, while for stiff polar crystals such as those treated by the Frohlich model, ionic vibrations often require a quantum description.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic bonds are not quantum, and this applies to other types of bonds such as covalent bonds. Atoms have some amount of thermal energy, causing them to vibrate, spin, and shake. When atoms are bonded to make molecules, they are still vibrating, spinning, and shaking. Thus, the bond length of any molecule is always slightly fluctuating due to the shaking, vibrating, and spinning of atoms inside molecules.

In fact, you can give a molecule so much thermal energy that the atoms spin, shake, and vibrate so violently that the molecule itself breaks apart due to massive fluctuations in the bond lengths.

Comment: This isn't correct. All confined systems show quantum behavior, but the energy spacing generally gets smaller as the system gets larger (and in an infinite solid the continuum approximation is good). A two-atom molecule in which there is a strongly preferred interatomic distance will have low-energy displacements described by a simple harmonic potential, but high-energy excitations may be non-harmonic. A rigid rotor has quantized energies proportional to $\ell(\ell+1)$.